# What is the difference between greater than and greater than or equal to with respect to normal distributions?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I am trying to solve the following 2 problems using standard normal distribution tables.

1. $P(0.53 < Z ≤ 2.06)$
2. $P(−0.79 ≤ Z < 1.52)$

However, I am confused about the role of the $\leq$ versus $<$ symbols. The answer key calculates the answer as if there was a $\leq$ on both boundary conditions. Do standard normal distribution tables ignore the boundary conditions by default?

Comment: The normal distribution is continuous, and for any continuous distribution $P(X=a)$ is $0$ for any $a$. This means that you will always get the same answer whether you use a strict or a non-strict inequality.

Comment: I see, so integrating we would get something like $\int_{x_0}^{x_0} f(x) dx = 0$.

Comment: Yes, precisely.